# Vector particles with nested for loops - collisions not detected

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, collision, particles

So I have some particles (ellipses) bouncing around the screen. I'm trying to get them to collide rather than pass over each other. In order to do this I must cycle through every particle and compare it's distance to every other particle with a for loop nested within another for loop, then tell their velocity to change when their points are a certain distance from each other like so:

```
//p.size() returns the size of the particle system (yes it works)
//ofDist() is an open frameworks function that calculates the dist between 2 points

for( int i = 0; i < p.size(); i++){
//        cout << i << endl;
    for(int j = 0; j < p.size(); j++){
//            cout << j << endl;
        pDist[i] = ofDist(p[i].pos.x, p[i].pos.y, p[j].pos.x, p[j].pos.y);
//            cout << pDist[i] << endl;
        if(pDist[i] <= 300){
            p[i].vel.x *= -1;
            p[i].vel.y *= -1;
            p[j].vel.x *= -1;
            p[j].vel.y *= -1;
        }
    }
}
```

But for some mysterious reason they still pass right over each other like they don't even exist. It **does** work if I apply this to just 2 particles without the for loops:

```
    pDist[0] = ofDist(p[0].pos.x, p[0].pos.y, p[1].pos.x, p[1].pos.y);

if(pDist[0] <= 300){
    cout << "It's colliding" << endl;
    p[0].vel.x *= -1;
    p[0].vel.y *= -1;
    p[1].vel.x *= -1;
    p[1].vel.y *= -1;
}
```

The particles are stored in a vector by the way.

Any ideas how I can get this to work with the for loops?

**update**
The size of my vector is 3, so `p.size() = 3` ( or 2, doesn't really make a difference right now). I substituted `p.size()` for 2 and 3 in my code and it didn't change anything, so that's not the source of the issue.

**update 2**
If someone could let me know what I need to do to not get downvoted that would be helpful. :/

Comment: Did you run a debugger ? what is the value of `p.size()` ?

Comment: If by debugger you're referring to things like syntax errors or variables that don't exist etc, I'm using XCode which seems to not let anything like that go undetected. `p.size()` = the amount of particles in the vector, currently 3.

Comment: Why `pDist[i] = `? Why not `double dist = `? Also, you know no particle is ever all that far from itself? Also, why don't you use [`ofDistSquared`](http://www.openframeworks.cc/documentation/math/ofMath.html#show_ofDistSquared) instead?

Comment: @A__ `debugger` normally is a tool that allows you to stop execution in your code and check what the state is.

Comment: In the .h file I have `int pDist[3];`.. I need this to be able to cycle between the amount of particles in the vector so I can plug `i` and `j` into it... sorry, what do you mean no particle is ever that far away from itself?

Comment: @SamIam Ah ok, I'm sure XCode has something like that (pretty new to it obviously), I will try to do this, but I'm not sure how much more help that is than logging things to the console at various points like I've been doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pretty large issue is that by saying:

```
for( int i = 0; i < p.size(); i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < p.size(); j++){
```

You are actually checking each particle against themselves. You are also checking particles collisions twice. By detecting a single collision twice, and inverting the velocity each time, you are essentially doing nothing( a * -1 * -1 = a ).

A better way to do this would be to use a loop where particles collisions are only checked once, and a particle is not checked against itself. You can do this by starting the nested loop after the current particle (essentially offsetting the index by the indexes that have already been checked), like so:

```
for( int i = 0; i < p.size()-1; i++){
    for(int j = i+1; j < p.size(); j++){
```

This also has the benefit of being significantly faster for a larger number of particles.

There is also no reason to store the calculated distance in an array (unless your code makes use of this somewhere else). Simply using a double would work fine here.

Edit:

Just to be a bit clearer, I have logged the output of the two arrays to demonstrate. I have used 3 particles in the array.

**Original loop**

1 compared to 1    (This is a problem. Checking a particle against itself)

1 compared to 2

1 compared to 3

2 compared to 1    (This is a problem. This has already been checked for)

2 compared to 2    (This is a problem. Checking a particle against itself)

2 compared to 3

3 compared to 1    (This is a problem. This has already been checked for)

3 compared to 2    (This is a problem. This has already been checked for)

3 compared to 3    (This is a problem. Checking a particle against itself)

**Modified loop**

1 compared to 2

1 compared to 3

2 compared to 3

As you can see, there are only three collisions checked for in the modified loop, and there are no double ups.

Comment: Ah, this is what Deduplicator was talking about. Thanks Chris, I appreciate the solution and detailed explanation.